# React Router Redux ConnectedRouter Not Updating With Route Change

Tags: redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux, react-router-v4

I'm running into an issue where ConnectedRouter is not updating history on route change.
On route change store gets updated history and Router (ConnectedRouter's child) gets updated history but ConnectedRouter's history stays same. The app doesn't render new component but the browser's url changes.

index

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux'
import AppContainer from './containers/app'
import { history, store } from './store'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <AppContainer />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

store

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import { rootReducer } from './reducers/root'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

export const history = createHistory()
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history)

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(middleware))
)
```

rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  router: routerReducer,
})
```

HeaderContainer

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { push } from "react-router-redux"
import { HeaderTemplate } from '../components/templates/header'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({
    pushRoute: location => dispatch(push(location)),
  }, dispatch)

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HeaderTemplate)
)
```

HeaderTemplate

```
import React from 'react'

export const HeaderTemplate = props => (
  <div className="content">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <SomeLink onClick={() => props.pushRoute('/')}>Link1</SomeLink>
        <SomeLink onClick={() => props.pushRoute('/test')}>Link2</SomeLink>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like what you are doing is wrapping the **HeaderContainer** with the `withRouter` but you should actually be wrapping the **AppContainer** with that assuming that the **AppContainer** has the actual `<Route />`'s inside of it.

Other than that the only thing I would say is to make sure you ran:

`npm install --save react-router-redux@next`

[in order to user the `ConnectedRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux#react-router-redux)

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing but I think I know your problem. I don't believe Router can be a child of ConnectedRouter, You need to REPLACE Router with ConnectedRouter and everything will work as expected.