# React Redux Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I did some updates to my app's packages like:

```
"react-redux": "^5.0.6" => "^6.0.1",
"redux": "^3.7.2" => "^4.0.1",
"redux-saga": "^0.16.0" => "^1.0.1"
```

but I get the error

> Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory';
import { writeSaga } from './sagas/writeSaga';
import { readSaga } from './sagas/readSaga';

import App from './App';
import reducers from './reducers';

const history = createHistory();
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [routerMiddleware(history), thunk, sagaMiddleware];
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export default function*  rootSaga() {
  yield [
    writeSaga(),
    readSaga(),
  ]
};
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app-container')
);
```

Here I get the error (react-router-redux ConnectedRouter.js):
[image: debugger]

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**
Adding/removing packages, I understood that the package that causes that issue is the upgrade of "react-redux" (5.0.6 => 6.0.1)

**UPDATE 2**
Watching the breaking changes of react-redux, I was able to understood that the problem was how I pass the store ([breaking changes](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0)).

I changed my code to:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history} store={store}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} store={store} />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app-container')
);
```

And it works!

But I know it isn't the correct way... maybe it can be useful for the right solution.

**Why this isn't a duplicate of the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093898/react-router-redux-connectedrouter-not-updating-with-route-change):** I have the same config to index, I checked it and I'm sure that I'm using react-router-redux.
In every page I export like

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/issues/609

Comment: @Daviti I don't use Apollo and isn't a good option introduce it now because I'm developing a big program

Comment: why use both [tag:redux-thunk] and [tag:redux-saga]?

Comment: you might have forgotten the `all` effect in `rootSaga()`

Comment: @codekaizer While thunk (with more interesting action creators) will act more like synced code, sagas will do it's job in a background. Can you explain better what do u mean with "all" effect in rootSaga? However this software works perfectly before the update..  Thanks

Comment: @mene, there's a reason why in `createStore()` it is `applyMiddleware` without an s.  in your `rootSaga()` you are yielding a list of generators without any [effect](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html).

Comment: @codekaizer in every saga I use `takeLatest`, `call` and `put` as effects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router Redux ConnectedRouter Not Updating With Route Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093898/react-router-redux-connectedrouter-not-updating-with-route-change)

Comment: @codekaizer I think not (view my edit on the main topic)

Comment: @mene - connect should accept two arguments. In case you don't use mapStateToProps you should pass a null instead. Try using it like so:
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)

Comment: @jank I also use "export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);". It depends by my page should do

Comment: @mene Did you come up with any alternative to your above fix?
Would be interested to know.
Your initial solution work for me also, so thanks :)

Comment: @uidevthing I don't find other solutions, still waiting for an answer :/ For now it's working well, however it isn't the best solution

Comment: @mene - I noticed your answer in the comments, However, did you try replacing `mapStateToProps` with `null`? (since you are not using it).

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app-container')
);
```

To:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history} store={store}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app-container')
);
```